# Processing many Zipped Files inside of a Zip File in Java

Tags: java, json, buffer, gzip, fileinputstream

I have a Scenario where I have to process JSON files using Java but, There is a Big .GZ file containing many .TAR files each containing 100 JSON files.

so its .gz containing .tar (containing .json's)

I cannot find any code on internet.

Any hint how can It be done.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("archive.tar.gz");
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("archive.tar");
GZipCompressorInputStream gzIn = new GZipCompressorInputStream(in);
final byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
int n = 0;
while (-1 != (n = gzIn.read(buffer))) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
out.close();
gzIn.close();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Beware that a "zip file" is not a tarball; the subject of your question is confusing

Comment: Also, do you use Java 7+? If yes your code can be improved quite a lot